# C++ Multilevel Inheritance, Polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose i have three classes A, B and C. class B inherits from class A and the inheritance is private whereas class C inherits from B and the inheritance is public. Now class A has a protected function which class C wants to access. So, what must be done in class B to make that protected function available to class C.

Here is the link to the code : http://pastebin.com/9E2sLZzj

Comment: If you haven't done it already, then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When `B` inherits privately from `A` then the protected members of `A` become private in `B`.Now when `C` inherits from `A`, you want to access that private member.So your problem reduces to finding a way to access private members from sub class which i don't think is available and even if available, is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "using" keyword makes a member of an inherited class visible, and resolvable, in the scope of its subclass. So, to make the privately-inherited member available to `B`'s subclasses:

```
class A {

protected:

    void foo() {}
};

class B : private A {

protected:

    using A::foo;
};

class C : public B {

    void bar()
    {
        foo();
    }
};
```

Comment: Code only answer? Please explain it

Comment: class `C` inherits from `A` while the OP wants `C` to inherit from `B`

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got the solution
This code fragment worked after inserting it into Class B.

```
int get(){
  return A::get();
}
```

Not sure what it does though